# How to set DIV background-image css jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Motto is to set/update(ajaxified) a DIV background image.

```
        $.getJSON("https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=" + searchTerm + '&limit=1' + '&callback=?', 
        function(data) {
        $.each(data.results, function() {
        var art = this.artworkUrl100;
        $('.photo').parent().css('background-image', 'url(' + art + ')');
      }
    }
```

On HTML i've this:

```
<div id="results" class="photo"></div>
```

Comment: What is the parent div that you are setting the background image on? Or are you wanting to set the background on the `.photo` div?

Comment: want to set background image on div class 'photo'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the background image to a parent element instead of the `.photo` div.

Try this:

```
$.getJSON("https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=" + searchTerm + '&limit=1' + '&callback=?', 
    function(data) {
        $.each(data.results, function() {
            var art = this.artworkUrl100;
            $('.photo').css('background-image', 'url(' + art + ')');
        })
});
```

If multiple `data.results` are returned then only the last be used for the background image due to the `$.each` loop that you are using. If you are maintaining the `limit=1` on the JSON call then this won't be a problem.